# How to add scrolling with multiple pages in xcode storyboards

Tags: ios, scroll, storyboard

I'm new at using xcode and building my first app so this is probably a simple solution, but I've scoured the web and can't find anything.
I'm using storyboards and am trying to get one of the pages to scroll. I tried this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nYM8EfTpRw and others like it, but it only works when the scrolling page is the first page. How do I get a page to scroll if I have multiple pages?

Comment: What are you trying to get to scroll?  An individual scene...?  Your storyboard?  Your question is completely unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that, trying to get a full page view controller to scroll

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling within UIScrollView depends on the content size of the scroll view. Try with below code based on your needs.

```
// For verical scrolling
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewToScroll.width, viewToScroll.height * numberOfPages);

// For horizontal scrolling
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewToScroll.width * numberOfPages, viewToScroll.height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works if I use the main page view but not any of the other pages. Any ideas for getting other pages to work?

Answer (score 0):

Read this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179) for detail information